# Массив из значений select

Tags: php, javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть `select` который формируется циклом **PHP**. мне нужно все значения `option` в нём собрать в массив через **js** и вывести его в другом `select`. Как это можно сделать. Прилагаю свой код

```
<?php

function rel_select() {
  global $wpdb;
  $table_cat = $wpdb->prefix . 'rel_cat';
  $rel_cat = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT name FROM $table_cat");
  ?>
  <select name="cat-select" id="category-select">
    <option value="">Select category</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($rel_cat as $key => $value):
      $key = 1;
      echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    endforeach;
    ?>
  </select>
  <?php
} ?>
```

а в этом месте мне нужно вывести options в новом select

```
 document.getElementById("cat_val"+id).innerHTML="<select id='cat_sel"+id+"' name='cat-select'> <option value='"+cat+"'></select>";
```

Comment: а просто скопировать старый селект и вставить его в нужное место, не подходит ?

Comment: нет. Я через js создавать должен

Comment: а кто сказал что через js нельзя копировать ?)))

Answer (score 2):

Короче, если я верно понял что нужно сделать, предлагаю просто скопировать селект, дать ему другой `id` и вставить в нужное место :

```js
var oldSelect = document.getElementById("select1");
var ddlId = 1;

function CreateNewDdl() {
  var newSelect = oldSelect.cloneNode(true);
  ddlId++;
  newSelect.id = 'select' + ddlId;

  document.getElementById("cat_val1").appendChild(newSelect);
};
```

```html
<select id="select1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button onclick="CreateNewDdl();">create ne ddl</button>
<br/>

<div id="cat_val1"></div>
```

Вот еще вариант (с использованием `innerHTML`):

```js
var oldSelect = document.getElementById("select1");
var ddlId = 1;

function CreateNewDdl() {
  document.getElementById("cat_val1").innerHTML += "<select id='cat_sel" + ddlId + "' name='cat-select'>" + oldSelect.innerHTML + "</select>";
  ddlId++;
};
```

```html
<select id="select1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button onclick="CreateNewDdl();">create ne ddl</button>
<br/>

<div id="cat_val1"></div>
```

Так-же можно достать все `option` у селекта в виде массива обьектов и в цикле пробежаться по ним, сделав в процессе все что угодно :

```js
var oldSelect = document.getElementById("select1");

function CreateNewDdl() {
  for (var i = 0; i < oldSelect.options.length; i++) {
    console.log(oldSelect.options[i].value);
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="select1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button onclick="CreateNewDdl();">click</button>
<br/>

<div id="cat_val1"></div>
```

Comment: Нет. я select создаю через inner.HTML мне нужно только сам значения options подставить. Новый селект там не нужен так как я должен потом в дальнейшем с строкой этой через которую вывожу, работать

Comment: которую выводите ? ето какая строка ?